# Modifying ASP.Net AccountController to write to two tables during registration

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to add to two tables (AspNetUsers and Administrators) when a new user is being registered.My RegisterViewModel has the following properties

```
FirstName
LastName
Email
PhoneNumber
status
Password
userType
```

in my AccountController Register method i have the following code

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser
            { 
                UserName = model.Email,
                Email = model.Email,                    
                Status = model.Status
                
            };
            
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            { 
                await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(user.Id, model.SelectedUserType);
                Administrator admin = new Administrator
                {
                    User_Id = int.Parse(user.Id),
                    FirstName = model.FirstName,
                    LastName = model.LastName,
                    PhoneNumber = model.PhoneNumber
                };

                _db.Admins.Add(admin);
                _db.SaveChanges();
                await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:false, rememberBrowser:false);                   
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            
            
            AddErrors(result);
        }
```

my problem when i run my app is that, where i create the Administrator object i get an input not in a correct format error. How can i fix this?

Comment: Can you specify which line get the error? What I guess is most probably from this line `int.Parse(user.Id)`. What is the type for `user.Id`? What value is `user.Id`? And what is the type for `User_Id`?

Comment: Where it says Administrator admin = new Administrator it's highlighted red with an "Input not in a correct format" error. User.Id is the primary key of the newly created user in AspNetUsers. User_Id is an integer, when I I wrote User_Id = user.Id i got "can't convert string to int so I did int.parse()

Comment: Okay, thanks for the details.  Your `user.Id` is with a string value, but the value cannot cast to integer correctly. Try to debug and see what is the value. Hard to help without knowing your real value.  But it's close to answer. Good luck!